# Upload 2GB file to Azure blob

Tags: azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

I have a zipped 2GB file that I need to upload to Windows Azure through my home cable connection, how long should I expect that this file gets uploaded? Has anyone averaged their upload time for their files?

Also when I do this to create a blob for uploading a file

```
        CloudBlob _blob = _container.GetBlobReference("file1");
```

is this creating `CloudBlockBlob` or `CloudPageBlob` by default? I have been using the above code to upload files and it has been quite slow.

Comment: This is actually quite hard to answer as your upload time would depend on a number of factors - your Internet speed, number of parallel threads you're using to upload the blob, size of individual blocks in which you're splitting your file etc.

Comment: You should split this into two questions. Well... the first part is unanswerable and doesn't fit the StackOverflow Q&A [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). The second part is completely separate, fits the guidelines, and can be answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CloudBlob _blob = _container.GetBlobReference("file1");
```

It does not create CloudBlockBlob or CloudPageBlob by default.

If you want to use CloudBlockBlob (Azure SDK v2.0):

```
// Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob".
CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob");
```

now split your file to a small pieces (4MB max), and upload each piece like this:

```
blob.PutBlock(blockId, memoryStream, null);
```

where: **blockId** is a base64-encoded block ID that identifies the block.

and **memoryStream** A stream that provides the data for the block.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee772903.aspx)